# Using Facebook graph api, can and should I cache profile picture?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, facebook-graph-api, sails.js, waterline

I am using log in with facebook in my web app. Because of this I will always have the userid of the current user at facebook. I want to use the profile picture in my app, I can do this easily by:

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<%- accountId %>/picture?width=200&height=200">
```

This seems fine if I just display the picture at the current users dashboard, but what if I want other users to see each others pictures? Is it a good idea to always link each users images as above? It will in this case be a bounch of requests to facebook for each view of my app. Or should I download each users profile pic when they register and display it from my database? Am I allowed to do that? In this case, how do I save the picture into my mongoDB database via waterline (sails.js)?